Why I didn't get the badge "Staging Ground Beta"?
The Staging Ground beta is now live, and it appears with a badge.
I asked to be in the beta here. I entered it, made a review, and also posted about the inactivity in it (because of the pause) here.
But I didn't get the badge for the beta. Is it reserved for reviewers from beta 1 (as I joined in beta 2), or is there another reason why I didn't get the badge?

No the badge isn't reserved for users part of Beta 1. I believe the reason you don't have the badge is because one of the criterias for getting it was to leave some feedback or post on the Stack Overflow Teams set up for the beta. Looking at your user there you didn't have any activity on the team.

Oh maybe, but I never know it was there, and I was waiting for a notification...

The awarding of the badges was somewhat of a manual process though (which is what Yaakov had mentioned) and they did miss out some people which on report were then awarded the badge so you might have a chance to get that badge yet. Maybe you left some feedback on the chatroom for the Beta and you can show that to fulfill the criteria.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I already made some partial feedback as report bug or ask few questions on chat but maybe not enough to get it... Sadly, I had something to said when the beta were here xd

I'd say that bug report counts as feedback, I don't believe the people awarding the badges looked for feedback here on Meta, consider highlighting that in your question and let's see if a staff happens on this and decides to award you the badge.

Ah but wait the question you reported the bug for didn't even go through the SG...

At least according to your profile there, you didn't leave feedback in the SG Beta Testing SOfT during a beta testing round, which is one of the criteria for being rewarded the badge.
